# How to correctly access existing files in the app data folder created with a Xamarin.Forms app inside a migrated MAUI app?

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin.forms, maui

I am currently migrating an existing Xamarin.Forms app to .NET MAUI. The existing app uses an SQLite database to store some data.

The database path was set up as follows in the Xamarin.Forms app:

```cs
public static string DatabasePath
{
    get
    {
        var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
        return Path.Combine(basePath, "mydb.db3");
    }
}
```

In Xamarin.Forms, the resulting path on Android is:

```
/data/user/0/my.app/files/.local/share/mydb.db3
```

However, when using the exact same code as above in MAUI, the resulting path on Android is:

```
/data/user/0/my.app/files/mydb.db3
```

This creates the problem that existing data cannot be accessed in MAUI, unless I modify the code as follows in the migrated code:

```cs
public static string DatabasePath
{
    get
    {
        var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);

#if ANDROID
        var localShare = ".local/share";

        if (!basePath.Contains(localShare))
        {
            basePath = Path.Combine(basePath, localShare);
        }
#endif

        return Path.Combine(basePath, "mydb.db3");
    }
}
```

Now, this would solve my issue, but I don't think this is the right way. Does anyone know how to correctly migrate paths that were obtained using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` in order to access the *exact* same path as before?

This is important, because I need to be able to access and reuse the existing local database that was created with the Xamarin.Forms version from within the migrated MAUI app.

***Note:** I am aware that there are file system helpers for [Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/essentials/file-system-helpers) and [MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers), but that doesn't help with this issue, because they weren't used when the Xamarin.Forms app was created.*

Comment: Just try both paths.

Comment: Yes, that would be a simple fix. I would like to understand, though, why this is the case and if there's a recommended migration path for this specific issue.

Comment: If it is a newly created default project, will the path also encounter this situation when connecting to the database?

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT Not sure, what exactly you mean. For existing as well as new Xamarin.Forms projects a call to `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` returns something like `/data/user/0/my.app/files/.local/share/mydb.db3` while in new MAUI projects the call returns a path similar to `/data/user/0/my.app/files/mydb.db3`.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your problem. Exactly, after upgrading Xamarin to Maui, the path of  `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` method is missing the `.local/share` part. It is recommended to [post this issue to github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

In addition, I found that the path to `LocalApplicationData` was mentioned in [File Storage and Access with Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/), but no documentation related to Maui was found.

So, in Maui, you can use the following method to refactor the code file path:

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFoler.Personal),".local/share/mydb.db3");
```

Although this is not much different from your solution, [it is the officially used refactor the code path method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/#reading-or-writing-to-files-on-internal-storage).

Comment: Thank you, I found those resources as well. I've started a [discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/21438) about this, because it's not a feature request or a bug. It requires clarification and an official migration path.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider working at a lower level to get a better understanding of the Android file system.

The following will always return the folder of your app containing your data.

```
// the main data folder only available to your app
Java.IO.File folder = ContextCompat.GetExternalFilesDirs(Application.Context, null)[0];
```

In the debugger, you’ll see the string as “/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/packagename/files”, where your package name is in the usual format “com.companyname.appname”

You may have a subfolder created when first run the app where you keep specific data.

So, then you can get to the data via

```
string appDataFolder = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder.Path, GetString(Resource.String.your_app_data_folder));
```

I may want to debug the content of a user’s data file. The user sends me the file I can then access the data from the Assets folder of the project on my device, so I can then if necessary debug the problem on my device with the user’s data.

```
string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(appDataFolder, diagnosticFileName);
using Stream asset = Assets!.Open(diagnosticFileName);

if (!File.Exists(filename))
{
    using FileStream fileStream = File.Create(filename);
    asset.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your insights, but this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I only mentioned it because the document referred to below is now way out of date. For instance, later versions of Android (12+) don't allow apps to write to external storage, unless they are something like a file explorer app and even then Google Play Console has to approve it.  Basically, external storage doesn't exist for normal apps. If suppose you need to make your data available to the user. In that case, you need to request permission from the user to create a folder in external storage and then copy the data to the folder the user created and granted permission to.

Comment: I think you're entirely misunderstanding my question. My file doesn't need to be available to the user. It's in the internal storage and will remain there. External storage has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: Sorry, but I did understand your question, I only pointed out that there was another way to get the folder with Android. My last point was to make people aware that the documentation is plainly outdated, including the use of External storage. I hope they address the issue you raised on dotnet/maui 2 days ago.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. The most appropriate way to get that folder in a cross-platform fashion is actually by using the filesystem helpers which I have linked for Xamarin.Forms and MAUI in the question. The documentation isn't outdated, it still applies for Xamarin.Forms and Android up to 12.0. There is no need to update it, Xamarin.Forms will be retired soon.

Comment: My point about the documentation is that Xamarin.Android is still viable right now. If you've already got a published Android 14 app, then that app is fine, until Google Play forces you to upgrade to Android 15 which is over 12 months away. In my opinion, the existing docs should reflect the changes required for the Android 12, 13 and 14 upgrades. The performance of my app converted to net8.0-android is markedly different as compared to the Xamarin.Android version which prevented me from publishing it. Hopefully, when I do convert it again they will have fixed those performance issues.